# How does difference in the format specifiers affect the value?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    float b = 10;
    double c = 15;
    printf("%d %f %lf\n", a, a, a);
    printf("%d %f %lf\n", b, b, b);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    printf("%d %f %lf\n", c, c, c);
    printf("%lf\n", c);
}
```

Output:

```
5 0.000000 0.000000
0 0.000000 0.000000
10.000000
0 0.000000 0.000000
15.000000
```

I fail to understand why it prints 0 in the first case for b and c, even for the proper matching format specifier?

I am using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong conversion specification invokes **undefined behavior**. You may get either expected or unexpected result or even program crash.

**C11:  7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: True but fairly vacuous for somebody trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: Moreover one might even get 42!

Comment: @luk32; Or even hard disk crash!

Comment: @haccks I thought that a compiler, that deliberately outputs 42 on UB,  would be a funny thing. But your idea completely overshadows it =).

Comment: @luk32; I like to ruin FUN! :P

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the C compiler is **not** clever enough to understand the format string and properly cast the following arguments. Therefore, your arguments will probably processed incorrectly; to `printf`, they are just some bytes on the stack. The representation of a `double` with a value of 15.0 most likely contains several bytes of 0 on the stack, which `printf` read as `int`s because you told it to do so in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're using the proper format specifier in part of the format string, but since you'd already used the incorrect format specifier *earlier* in the format string, you've already caused all hell to break loose.

Specifically, `printf` has already gotten "out of alignment" with your data arguments by the time it gets to substituting the `%f` and `%lf` bits.